# I can't seem to reference a class inside App_Code for model to get web config strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm working on a project where we're trying to encapsulate all references of two databases on two different servers. We have this in a "utilities" file inside App_Code:

```
 public static string myFirstDBName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firstDbName"];
        public static string mySecondDBName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secondDbName"];
```

Which we can reference in any Controller no problem.

However, when I try to reference this in a model it doesn't see it - I tried a using statement and it didn't work. I'm hoping to pull this out of the model and put it in the same utilities file:

```
private readonly string _myFirstDBName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firstDBName"];
private readonly string _mySecondDBName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secondDBName"];
```

Can someone tell me if I'm missing anything? Or should we be putting this utilities file somewhere else? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added my web.config values to correspond with this question:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="firstDBName" value="db1" />
    <add key="secondDBName" value="db2" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try web.Config

```
<configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
            <add name="DBName" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=uid;Password=pwrd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

you can also add app settings in web.Config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="KEY" value="VALUE" />
  </appSettings>
```

update in regards to comment...

take this example

```
Model m = new Model();
m.prop = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firstDBName"];
m.prop2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secondDBName"];
return View("VIEWNAME", m);
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that... I'll alter my answer to show the web config stuff - but I don't know how to pull it down into my Model?

Comment: What's the difference between using WebConfigurationManager and System.Config.ConfigurationManager?